# Delete elements of two list with same index in python

Tags: python

I have two lists `p` & `p2` with the same size, and a third list `s`.
I wanna remove the elements of `p2` that have the same index location with those elements of `p` that exist in `s`:

An example would help understanding:

```
p = ['a','b','c','d','e']
p2 = [11,12,13,14,15]
s = ['a','d']
p2 = [i in p2 for i in p if i not in s]
print p2

# output of this: [False, False, False]
# wanted output: [12,13,15]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can `p` contain duplicates?

Comment: `[b for a,b in zip(p,p2) if a not in s]` (make `s` a set if you do this many times)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes, it can have duplicate elements.

Comment: @KarimPazoki So if `p = ['a', 'b', 'b', 'd']`, `p2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]` and `s = 'b'` what does the result look like? `p2 = [1, 4]` or `p2 = [1, 3, 4]`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis p2 = [1, 4]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn `s` into a `set` for efficiently checking whether an item is in it or not, and do:

```
p = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
p2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
s = set(['a','d','h','i'])

[num for num, letter in zip(p2, p) if letter not in s ]
# [12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and enjoy!

```
p = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
p2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
s = ['a','d','h','i']
p2 = [j for i,j in zip(p,p2) if i not in s]
print p2
```

#### Edit:

At the time of writing above solution, condition of repetitions weren't mentions. Multiple answers for that conditions is already posted. Below is my version though.
-Thanks

```
p = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
p2 = [11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
s = ['a','d','h','i']
p2 = [j for i,j in zip(p,p2) if i not in set(s)]
print p2
```

Answer (score 0):

> I see i am a little late to the party, but here is my two examples

```
#looking for match and printing index number
number = 0
for char in p:
    if char in s:
        print('found match at index: %d with: %s' %(number,char))
        number += 1
    else:
        print('index: %d did not match' %(number))
        number += 1
#printing if its not a match the desired output you wanted
number2 = 0    
for char in p:
    try:
        if char in s:
            number2 += 1
        else:
            print(p2[number2])
            number2 += 1
    except IndexError:
        print('end of list')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Python` has `index` and `pop` function, so you need to use it.

```
In [42]: p = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']

In [43]: p2 = [11,12,13,14,15]

In [44]: s = ['a','d']

In [45]: index_list = [p.index(i) for i in s]

In [46]: output = [p2.pop(index) for index in index_list]

In [47]: output
Out[47]: [11, 15]
```